# Hola mundo SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Estoy " intentando " lanzar el hola mundo del SpringBoot para los servicios Rest, Documentación diría que hay poca y mal explicada...

De momento estoy siguiendo estos enlaces:

http://programmingbabel.blogspot.com/2017/09/crear-una-aplicacion-con-spring-boot.html
https://programmingbabel.blogspot.com/2017/09/crear-una-aplicacion-con-spring-boot-2.html

Comento:

--Tengo el Eclipse , he creado un proyecto con maven, lo he puesto con devtools y con boot y restRepository

He forzado el pom.xml he creado un nuevo controlador:

miController.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class miController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String raiz() {
        return "Bienvenido!!!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("saludo")
    String saludo() {
        return "Hola !!!!!!!!!!";
    }  

}
```

Cuando lo arranco

```
Usage: RealmBase [-a <algorithm>] [-e <encoding>] [-i <iterations>] [-s <salt-length>] [-k <key-length>] [-h <handler-class-name>] <credentials>
```

Y lógicamente el localhost/8080 no me hace nada.

Comment: Estimado, espero que estés entrando en http://localhost:8080 y no en http://localhost/8080 como escribiste en tu post. Saludos!

Comment: @Fabrizzio puedes generar un nuevo proyecto desde su pagina https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona.